# Excel - Identify Recurring Value in Same Row in a range of multiple columns

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

HelloI
i am new here and need help.Thanks in advance

I have to create a duty roster. in this , i wanted

1. identify and highlight rows with same names which have duty on consecutive days so that i can avoid clash...  i did this successfully by following tutorial http://trumpexcel.com/search-in-excel-conditional-formatting/
   using this conditional formatting formula
   =AND($C$2<>"",OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,$C6:$F6))))

where C2 is cell linked to search box
image of this formula is here

2. Second which i wanted is to identiy same names which have duty on same  date. i want another excel conditional formula which would highlight same names if they recur on same date e.g. as AB is in same row , i want these columns to be highlighted so i can avoid calsh of duties on same day

The excel file link is here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kehhyna3soo9xfq/Duty%20Roster.xlsx?dl=0

---

My actual roster has range is from column C to X , and rows 8 to 38

Waiting anxiously , Thanking you in advance

Comment: So, what is you expectation? If there are two same name in same row, then the row will be highlighted.

Comment: at the moment , row gets highlighted even when there is one or two names in the row... it does not get me info if one name is present twice or thrice on the same row.... i want if there are two same names in the same row , those columns should get highlighted with ANY OTHER COLOUR

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula in conditional formatting:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C6:$F6,$C$2)>=2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

[Solved file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tclR2RVk4cmo1aWM/view?usp=sharing)

***Note:*** `It will highlight that row, which have two or more name typed in text box.`